# File access denied while moving file

Tags: c#, file-handling, access-denied

I'm trying to move files from a to b, but I get an IOException with the Information: Access denied.

I'm pretty sure it's because the file is still open. My question is - how can I check if the file is in use or not, and if it is wait until it's closed.

The exception is thrown at the `MoveTo()` call in the example below.

```
public void CreateCheckedStructure() { 

    List<string> checkedDirNew = RemoveTempFolders(GetAllFromDir(Settings.Default.NewFolder));
    List<string> checkedDirCurrent = RemoveTempFolders(GetAllFromDir(Settings.Default.CurrentFolder));

    if (checkedDirNew.Count != 0 && checkedDirCurrent.Count != 0) {
        MyLog.WriteToLog("Moving Checked Files", MyLog.Messages.Info);
        foreach (string checkedNew in checkedDirNew) {
            DirectoryInfo dirInfoNew = new DirectoryInfo(checkedNew);
            foreach (string checkedCurrent in checkedDirCurrent) {
                DirectoryInfo dirInfoCurrent = new DirectoryInfo(checkedCurrent);
                if (dirInfoNew.Name.Equals(dirInfoCurrent.Name)) {
                    string checkedFoldersPath = Settings.Default.CheckedTables + "\\" + dirInfoCurrent.Name + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh-mm-ss");
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(checkedFoldersPath);
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(checkedFoldersPath + "\\New");
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(checkedFoldersPath + "\\Current");
                    dirInfoCurrent.MoveTo(checkedFoldersPath + "\\Current\\" + dirInfoNew.Name);
                    dirInfoNew.MoveTo(checkedFoldersPath + "\\New\\" + dirInfoCurrent.Name);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        MyLog.WriteToLog("All Checked Files have been moved", MyLog.Messages.Info);
    } else { MyLog.WriteToLog("No Temporary Folder for Zips found",MyLog.Messages.Warning); }
}
```

Comment: In our application, we catch the exception, wait for some seconds, try it again. if after tried X times, if still failed, then something went wrong. We threw exception.

Comment: This is exactly what Exception handling is for. Put a try/catch block (catch on `IOException`) around the failing code and handle the exception by returning a message or doing something else like scheduling a retry later or asking the user to try later.

Comment: okay thats a pretty clear awnser :D thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this extension method which I wrote to solve similar type of problem

```
public static async Task<bool> TryToAsync( Action action, int timeoutInSeconds )
        {
            var timeout = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds( timeoutInSeconds );
            while ( DateTime.Now < timeout )
            {
                try
                {
                    action();
                    return true;
                }
                catch ( Exception )
                {
                    await Task.Delay( 200 );
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
```

Comment: THANK YOU! that is exactly what i'm looking for. great method!

Comment: I am using c#6 which supports this